# Could I measure an annotation generic type from annotated member in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, annotations

Scala experts from StackOverflow.

On the sample code bellow I've reproduced an behavior I'm facing on a project I'm working on. I should be able to infer/measure the annotation "weapon" generic type defined when it is present in a class field member.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

class Reflection

object Reflection {

  def reflect[T: TypeTag](x: Class[T]): Type = {
    typeOf[T]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var tpe = reflect(classOf[Hero])
    for (member <- tpe.members)
      for (annotation <- member.annotations)
        annotation.tpe match {
          case t if t <:< typeOf[weapon[_]]
                  => println(s"found weapon member: $member")
          case t if t <:< typeOf[action]
                  => println(s"found action member: $member")
        }
  }
}

class weapon[T <: WeaponType](x: String = null) extends StaticAnnotation
class action extends StaticAnnotation
class WeaponType(damage: Int)
case class Knife extends WeaponType(12)

class Hero {

  @weapon[Knife] var weapon: String = _
  @action def hitWithKnife() {

  }

}
```

Yet, at the sample code I provided I couldn't be able to avoid the REPL to print a weird log as

```
 [] ?_$1 setInst sample.Knife
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

'@alexwriteshere' explains me rightly the reason the log was boring me. He makes me think that my question was confused.

**The Question**

It's possible to infer/measure the T type defined on @weapon at a class member ( as seen at weapon member from my Hero class ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the stdout, this is an [issue](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-language/131p4r0pf3/scala-reflection-spamming-to-system-out-at-runtime-2-10-0-release) in 2.10.0 and 2.10.1.

To get the type of `Knife`, you could do:

```
val paramType: Type = t.asInstanceOf[TypeRefApi].args.head
```

Then you can match it against instances of Type.

Comment: Thanks for the quick explanation. I was searching for this log issue without success. But I would like to infer the T type set on @weapon on my Hero class. I think I've failed explaining the problem.

Comment: Added the way to get the argument of the annotation. Is this what you're looking for?